# std::set_intersection of struct objects

Tags: c++, stl, set, containers, constants

I'm trying to get an intersection of two sets that stores objects of type of a struct called `dist`, using `std::set_intersection`. I want the result to be stored in another `set<dist>`.

However, compiler gives the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:64,
             from /home/kirill/CLionProjects/contest/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OutputIterator std::__set_intersection(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare) [with _InputIterator1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>; _InputIterator2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>; _OutputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:5122:48:   required from ‘_OIter std::set_intersection(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _OIter) [with _IIter1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>; _IIter2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>; _OIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<dist>]’
/home/kirill/CLionProjects/contest/main.cpp:65:73:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:5076:16: error: passing ‘const dist’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
      *__result = *__first1;
            ^
/home/kirill/CLionProjects/contest/main.cpp:26:8: note:   in call to ‘dist& dist::operator=(const dist&)’
 struct dist {
    ^
CMakeFiles/contest.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/contest.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/contest.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/contest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/contest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/contest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/contest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'contest' failed
make: *** [contest] Error 2
```

Here is a struct definition:

```
struct dist {
    int x_dist;
    int y_dist;

    bool operator<(dist const & b) const {
        return tie(x_dist, y_dist) < tie(b.x_dist, b.y_dist);
    }
};
```

Here I'm invoking a `set_intersection` method:

```
#define all(c) (c).begin(), (c).end()
void intersection_taxi_fan() {
    intersection.clear();
    set_intersection(all(taxi_dist), all(fan_dist), intersection.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass `intersection.begin()` as parameter of `set_intersection` because it is iterator to const value

> *Note: All iterators in a set point to const elements.
>   [from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/]

and `set_intersection` modifies value (in line [1] in below snippet code of `set_intersection` algorithm) which is pointed by this iterator.

```
    else if (*first2<*first1) ++first2;
else {
  *result = *first1;   // [1] try modifying const value
  ++result; ++first1; ++first2;
}
```

Const-object cannot be modified.

You can use `std::inserter` to insert elements into your `intersection` set

```
    set_intersection(all(taxi_dist), all(fan_dist), inserter(intersection, intersection.end()));
```

Comment: More relevant than const or non-const is the fact, that `set::begin()` does not return a valid iterator after `set::clear()` has been called. So OPs code would be wrong, even if `set::begin()` would return iterator to non-const value. Your solution is correct, but the explanation could be improved.